# The dataset in ng2 charts for bar graph is not setting properly

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am creating a bar chart using ng2 charts library. in the template I have added the following code

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas baseChart
    [datasets]="getBarChartData()"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

In component.ts file I have added the following lines of code, Here I am using a function depending on range I am changing the color of the bar dynamically, but the bar size  is not shown properly if I use this line of code it works properly.

```
barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [{
    data: [80, 12, 200, 137, 164, 4, 10, 35],
    label: 'A Bar Chart',
    backgroundColor: ['#99ccff', '#808080']
}];

export class BarchartComponent {
    constructor(private data: ChartService) {}
    barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true
    };
    barChartLabels: Label[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
    barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
    barChartLegend = true;
    barChartPlugins = [];


    getBarChartData() {
        const dataSets = [80, 12, 200, 137, 164, 4, 10, 35];
        const low = 2;
        const high = 5;
        const colors = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < dataSets.length; i++) {
            if (i >= (low - 1) && i <= (high- 1)) {
                colors.push('#99ccff')
            } else {
                colors.push('#808080')
            }
        }
        const barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [{
            data: dataSets,
            label: 'A Bar Chart',
            backgroundColor: colors
        }];
        return barChartData;
    }
}
```

The problem is the bar graph values are not completely displayed. can someone help me how to set the data for bar with the above example.
[image]

Comment: You should first review the `for loop` that furnishes the `colors` array and make sure, `colors` ends up having the same number of entries as `dataSets`. Currently `colors` misses one entry.

Comment: @uminder I have changed in for loop and now I get same eneteries in colors, but still the bar graph value is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to Angular change detection that runs constantly and has to evaluate the `datasets` property of the `canvas` again and again. This way the chart is constantly updated and Chart.js can no longer draw it correctly.

Avoid using the function `getBarChartData()` directly in the `HTML` but create a `barChartData` property in the component class instead.

```
<canvas baseChart 
  [datasets]="barChartData"
  ...
```

This `barChartData` property could be furnished in the `ngOnInit` method as follows:

```
barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  
ngOnInit() {
  this.barChartData = this.getBarChartData();
}
```

Please take a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-5ukz7a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and see how it works.